Unable to Click Download Button on Chess.com Using Selenium
I'm new to using Selenium and have successfully automated a process to log in to a website, navigate to the desired page, and upload a document. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to download a GIF. Selenium fails to click the download button, resulting in a TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace). Here is the code snippet that I'm using to click the button:
download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    "button.cc-button-component.cc-button-primary.download-button-button"))
)

download_button.click()

The webpage I'm working with is: https://www.chess.com/analysis?tab=analysis. After uploading a PGN file and navigating to Share -> Animated Gif, there is a download button. The script runs smoothly until this point, where it fails to click the download button.
I've tried different selectors like XPath, increased the wait time, and verified that it's not within an iframe. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

maybe button is in <iframe> - and this needs driver.switch_to.frame(...)

you may also first get all button and display classes for every of them to check if there are no extra string or space.

if it needs to upload image then you could add some example - so we could use it for test. And It could be better if you would create minimal working code so we could test it with this image. You don't have to add login/password because eventually we can create own account

maybe you should search by other element - it seems it has download="" - (By.XPATH, '//button[@download=""]') or probably (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[download=""]'. Or using text Download - (By.XPATH, '//button[span[text()="Download"]]')
